# `UIGestureRecognizer` hit testing

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

Are `UIViews`s hit tested for `UIGestureRecognizers` [in the same way](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4MPks3aB_D8C&pg=PA551&lpg=PA551&dq=hitTest:withEvent:+overlapping+views&source=bl&ots=lXCudl9-FL&sig=cyQZylGDOF0-Gq6QGlnx7ERlavQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBGoVChMIw7XKlrPTyAIVSMAUCh0q8Aln#v=onepage&q=hitTest%3AwithEvent%3A%20overlapping%20views&f=false) as they are for touch events? In particular, is the same `hitTest:withEvent:` method used?

This would mean a gesture recogniser in a view covered over by a transparent view will not be found, unless `hitTest:withEvent:` is tweaked to make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Gesture Recognisers are just treated like subviews when it comes to moving up the responder chain so yes they would use the same hit testing method as regular views.

To answer your last question.

Yes, if you have a `UIView` with a gesture recogniser and overlay it with a transparent view (caveat: it has to have `userInteractionEnabled = YES`) then the gesture recogniser will not fire.

You can see a nice example of getting around this sort of thing in the [WWDC 2014 session 235](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=235): "Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques". The transcript might become available [here](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/235).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Wasn't sure how to link directly to a session... I do now :D

Comment: :-) I think it varies by year. A new language with a live coding environment is surely wonderful, but being able to reliably link to session videos might be even better. Great video, by the way, thanks.

Comment: on that note, the very new http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491311/how-do-i-link-to-a-wwdc-sessions-in-s-o-answers/24491312#24491312 could use a +1 :-)

Comment: From the video, it seems like gestures do use the same hit testing methods of touches – would it be worth adding that to the answer? I'm happy to edit.

Comment: Added, I thought that was the case but I wasn't 100% sure. Thanks