# How do I link to a WWDC sessions in S.O. answers?

Tags: ios, wwdc

I'd like to provide relevant links to specific Apple's [WWDC session videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) in Stack Overflow questions & answers. How can I obtain a URL to link *directly* to a specific WWDC video? Ideally it would open a page with the session description and begin playing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the Stack Overflow meta, as the user is asking about how to do things with their posts.

Comment: @nhgrif The question asks how to obtain a link to a WWDC video, not how to put a link in to a stack overflow question / answer. I've updated a little to clarify this. The (self authored) answer reflects this. The votes and comments indicate that it has been of some use to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Videos

Use the following link format (*tested for 2014 & 2013*):

```
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/<the-year-here>/?id=<the-session-number-here>
```

For example: [`https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=228`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=228)

## Transcripts

An archive of session transcripts exists at http://asciiwwdc.com. Their format is:

```
http://asciiwwdc.com/<the-year-here>/sessions/<the-session-number-here>
```

For example: [`http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/302`](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/302)

They are thin on the ground as yet, but big ones are there (keynotes). It's worth throwing in a placeholder in hope of more content arriving.

## Linking Pleasure

If you use a lot of links, and who doesn't love the jolly scamps, take a look at SO's own guide to [markdown linking](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links). You can do some cool stuff you might not know about.